# Finding the norm of the sum of two vectors

Tags: vectors, normed-spaces

￼So, there's this thing called "dipole moment" ($\vec{\mu}$) in chemistry. It's basically a vector. An example of that would be a water molecule:

[dipole moment of $\mathrm{H_2O}\ (\vec{\mu_{\mathrm{H_2O}}})$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4ix1.jpg)

As you can tell by the picture, this should be the sum of the two vectors, $\vec{\mu_{\mathrm{OH_{(1)}}}}$ and $\vec{\mu_{\mathrm{OH_{(2)}}}}$, with $||\vec{\mu_{\mathrm{OH_{(1)}}}}|| = ||\vec{\mu_{\mathrm{OH_{(2)}}}}|| = ||\vec{\mu_{\mathrm{OH}}}||$.

The problem is that the formula given in the textbook is:
$$\vec{\mu_{\mathrm{H_2O}}} = \vec{\mu_{\mathrm{OH_{(1)}}}} + \vec{\mu_{\mathrm{OH_{(2)}}}}
\Rightarrow\ ||\vec{\mu_{\mathrm{H_2O}}}|| = 2\ ||\vec{\mu_{\mathrm{OH}}}||\ \cos{\frac{a}{2}}$$

where $\frac{a}{2} = 52^{\circ}$ as shown in the picture.

How do we arrive at this formula mathematically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of simpler notation, write $v_i := \vec{\mu_{\rm OH_{(i)}}}$, $i=1,2$, and $v:= \vec{\mu_{\rm H_2O}}$. Let $\langle\,\cdot\,{,}\,\cdot\,\rangle$ denote the standard scalar product on $\mathbb R^2$. Then we have $\lVert x\rVert^2 = \langle x,x\rangle$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^2$ by definition.
Recall, that the angle $\alpha$ between two vectors $x,y\in \mathbb R^2$ is defined by $\cos(\alpha) = \frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\lVert x\rVert\cdot \lVert y\rVert}$ (this makes sense since the right side takes values only in $[-1,1]$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality).

Back to the question. By assumption we have $\lVert v_1\rVert = \lVert v_2\rVert$. Now, using $v = v_1+v_2$, we calculate
$$\begin{align*}
\lVert v_1\rVert^2 &= \langle v_1,v_1\rangle = \langle v-v_2, v-v_2\rangle\\
&=\langle v,v\rangle - 2\cdot \langle v,v_2\rangle + \langle v_2,v_2\rangle\\
&= \lVert v\rVert^2 -2\cdot \lVert v\rVert\cdot \lVert v_2\rVert\cdot \cos(\alpha/2) + \lVert v_2\rVert^2
\end{align*}$$
where $\alpha/2$ is the angle between $v$ and $v_2$. Because of $\lVert v_1\rVert = \lVert v_2\rVert$ and $\lVert v\rVert\neq 0$ we can rearrange to get
$$
\lVert v\rVert = 2\cdot\lVert v_2\rVert\cdot \cos(\alpha/2).
$$

Answer (score 0):

See all we need is finding components . From picture its clear that $u_{OH_{1}}.cos52+...=u_{OH}$ '..'indicates same for other OH.I hope you know how this rotation is done ie finding components . Same for $u_{OH_{2}}$ thus as both of them are in same side thus they will be added . So $u_{H_{2}O}=2u_{OH}cos(52)$ hope its clear.

Comment: Writing that nu,mu is difficult so replaced it by u

Answer (score 0):

If you do the addition tip to tail, you should see that the only components of $\vec{\mu_1} = \vec{\mu_{\mathrm{OH_{(1)}}}}$ and $\vec \mu_2 = \vec{\mu_{\mathrm{OH_{(2)}}}}$  which add are those along the $\vec{\mu_{\mathrm{H_2O}}}$ direction and that these components are equal.

The magnitude of the component of $\vec \mu_1$ in the direction of $\vec{\mu_{\mathrm{H_2O}}}$ is given by $||\mu_1||\cos53$ so the overall magnitude of $\mu_1+\mu_2$ has to be twice that.  Which gives you $2||\mu_1||\cos53$